# Getting value of an HTML array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, html

I have an array of input boxes like so.

```
<form>
  9 <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="9">
  10 <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="10">
  11 <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="11">
</form>
```

I need the values stored in the date array, to pass it to an ajax call.

I've tried

```
    console.log($("input[name^=date]").val());
```

But this only outputs 9. I could always check if the individual elements are checked and then get their values, make an array and pass it to the ajax call, but is there a way to do this directly?

EDIT : Why does the `console.log($("input[name^=date]").val());` output 9 only?

Comment: First line from http://api.jquery.com/val/ : Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements. (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're submitting the data via ajax, you just need to `serialize` the form to get all the data, **already URL-encoded**:

```
 $('form').serialize();
```

For example, if all checkboxes  are selected, you will get the following data:

```
date%5B%5D=9&date%5B%5D=10&date%5B%5D=11 
//which is date[]=9&date[]=10&date[]=11
```

And `PHP` can comfortably handle the array parameter: `date[]`.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about .serialize(). jQuery continues to surprise me!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var values = $("input[name='date[]']:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

`values` will be an array of the values of the checked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `each`

```
var arr = []
$("input[name^=date]").each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).val())

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9xwmmxu/)